# layout_centerInParent in a RelativeLayout doesn't center on emulator or device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I have a fragment with this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Fragment"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Android Studio preview, I'm seeing this:

[image]

Which is fine, but on the emulator or on a real device I see:

[image]

What am I missing? How do I center that text in the parent?

The parent layout is the `FrameLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post xml file of parent also.

Comment: Agree with @RumitPatel. Try to check if parent tag also has android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: post full xml..

Comment: Change FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: Just set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`to fragmeLayout. and you are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change width of your **`FrameLayout`**

Change your `FrameLayout` width to **`android:layout_width="match_parent"`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Never though about the parent layout. `match_parent` did the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these properties:

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: Thanks but I have the same behavior.

Comment: This will not work because in this code `FrameLayout` is  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. Check @Nilesh Rathod answer - it is good answer

Comment: Parent Layout wasn't added when i answered the question. @TamirAbutbul

Comment: Well , that I did not knew

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your [frame layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout). Go through its documentation to read the details.

Fix the frame layout in the parent XML content:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"/>
```